# The Divide of array

Tags: dynamic-programming, trie

I found this problem on an online judge and I dun know how to solve it. Can any generous guy help me to come up with a solution. The tag suggests that the problem can be solved using trie and dynamic programming.
Time limit: 1.00s
Task description

You are given sequence of N integer numbers A[0], A[1], ..., A[N-1] and integer number M. What is the maximal number of non-empty parts you can split the sequence to, so that XOR (excluding OR) of all numbers in each part is not exceeding M? Each number of sequence must be in exactly one part. Each part must be a continuous subsequence.

Input Format

The first line of input consists of two integers (1<=N<=100000) and M.
The second line of input consists of N space-separated integers A[0], A[1], ..., A[N-1].
Output Format

Output the maximal number of parts, or -1 if you cannot split the sequence.